# Quantum Measurements : Is there a mistake in Eq.91 where independence of wiener process is removed

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurements

[image]

Here, by introducing inefficient measurement the Weiner process independency for each channels has been removed. It is clear when going From Eq.90 to Eq.91. But again in the measurement record which is in Eq.92, the independence is still there represented with \dd W_{n}, Is there a mistake in Eq.91 ?